# Anyway to speed up this exponentially expensive python code?

Tags: python, performance

I know I can use cython for a quick and dirty improved, but before that is there any way to speed up the code using pythonic way?

This code is aiming at generating features of polynomial on a hermite basis, can extended to any dimension, which is aiming a generalized feature generation for all possible cases in polynomials.

```
data_row = 4000;
n_components = 14;
q = n_components;
degree = 1

x= np.random.rand(data_row, n_components)

feature_list = []
feature_array = np.zeros((data_row, (degree + 1)**q))
from itertools import product
num = 0
for feature_combination in product(xrange(degree+1), repeat = q):
    # iterate over all feature combinations
    single_combination_feature = 1;
    for i_component, current_hermite_degree in enumerate(feature_combination):
        single_combination_feature *= polyval(hermitenorm(current_hermite_degree), x[:, i_component])

    feature_array[:, num] = single_combination_feature
    num += 1
```

Comment: Try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If you decide to move it to Code Review, make sure you add a description of what problem your program is supposed to solve.

Comment: It *looks* like this may be vectorizable using numpy instead of python for-loops, but perhaps at the cost of memory.